# Help with retrieving your profile via LinkedIn's API?

Tags: php, oauth, linkedin-api

I want to display some key fields from my linkedin profile on my personal website. From what I understand of linkedin's API, I would need to do the following:

1. Setup a developer account & get the api key and secret
2. Using the key and secret, go through the OAuth authentication and obtain an access token for my own account
3. Once I have an access token, I can query the profile api for the relevant fields

What would be an easy way of getting the access token? I understand once I get the access token, I can use it for as long as I want unless I expire it via my linkedin user account. Is my understanding correct?

I'm using php5 and I dont think my webhost has PECL OAuth module compiled in.

Comment: u might want to use this to get ur accesstoken, but the problem again is that linkedin requires signing ALL requests, and the signature evaporates pretty quickly :( http://term.ie/oauth/example/client.php

Answer (score 0):

If you  have linkedin account then login into the developer site http://developer.linkedin.com/index.jspa

Create a new application from https://www.linkedin.com/secure/developer to generate the API key.

Get started documentation: http://developer.linkedin.com/docs/DOC-1008

JavaScript API http://developer.linkedin.com/docs/DOC-1206

Answer (score 0):

satrun77 has the basic workflow correct in terms of creating a new application and getting your application keys.  As you mentioned, you then need to authenticate your application; once you have done that LinkedIn will send back your access token, which you can then store and use on any subsequent calls.  In your case, you would be just doing this for yourself, but the basic premise would work for any user.

If you want to connect to the API via PHP without the PECL OAuth extension, there is an open-source library specifically for that, along with a demo script showing basic functionality that you can use to get started:

http://code.google.com/p/simple-linkedinphp/

Comment: Ok, linkedin docs don't mention the duration for which the access token is valid. Can I assume that the token is valid as long as I dont go into my linkedin user account and expire the token manually i.e. de-authenticate my app?

Edit: Thanks for pointing to the simple-linkedinphp library.

Comment: When you authenticate the application, the login screen gives you a duration option; the default is to never expire.

Comment: i tried that, the accesstoken doesnt expire, but the signature of every url call DOES expire pretty fast, so what is the use of having an unlimited token if i need to sign the request everytime? i mean, im just displaying MY PROFILE... so weird, twitter doesnt do that

Comment: @Ayyash: the benefit of having and storing an unlimited access token means that you don't need to ask the user for authentication with every call to the API.  Using one of the available libraries for the API that handles all of the signing, etc makes things much simpler.